# How to check if a key is empty in map<int,pair<int,int>> - C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl

I have a

```
unordered_map<int, vector<pair<int, int> > > revert;
```

How do I check if some key is not present in the map
If I apply

```
revert[id].size()==0
```

condition , its be default size is some big number 107374182.
How do I check if its empty??

I tried to add breakpoint and debug , and that is where I found that its default size is a very big number and the condition is failing. Could you please help me with this? Thanks a lot

Comment: `revert.find(id)`

Comment: revert.find(id)==revert.end()???

Comment: "its be default size is some big number 107374182." the size of a default created vector should be `0`. If you get anything else then there is something wrong in your code

Comment: Note that `107374182` is `0x66666666` in hex which is probably some debug value

Comment: If you want to check if the vector for the key is empty then `revert[id].size()==0` is just right. If you want to check if there is a value in the map for key `id` then you need something else. In any case you should post a [mcve], and expected and actual output

Comment: `revert[id].size()==0` -- Using `[]` will add an entry to the map if `id` does not exist as a key in the map.  Is this your intention?  If not, use `find()`.  If you are using `[]` to do lookups and searches, then maybe your misuse of `operator []` is causing issues that you have mentioned, where the map is growing without you knowing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`revert[id].size()==0` will access the `size()` function a newly created `std::vector` if nothing was inserted with key `id` before. I'm not sure why the size is this big random number here and I have no way to check without a full example.

To correctly check if an entry with key `id` exists in `revert` you can use `revert.conains(id)` ([documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/contains)) if you are using C++-20, or `revert.find(id) != revert.end()` ([documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find)) otherwise.

Comment: The vector won't be uninitialised, it'll be default constructed

Comment: @AlanBirtles to be honest, I didn't check that. But because in the question, some random number is returned as size, I'd assume it's uninitialized here.

edit: I did check it and you are right. I'm not sure why the question says that the size is this random number. Doesn't happen for me. I will edit the answer.

Comment: we don't know why that number comes out due to the lack of a [mre]. There is likely undefined behaviour somewhere in the program that is corrupting something somewhere